# Pass Query String variable into contact form email

Tags: php

I have an application form on my page.  Everything is working correctly except for the query string.  I want to take a url with a variable, and pass it into the contact form email.  Ex. http://www.example.net?merchantid=12345

I want the merchant id variable name and value to display on the email I receive, along with the rest of the user information.  The way it sits now breaks my page.  It would be great to send a CC email without this merchant id as well.

Here is my markup:

```
<form id="shortApplication" action="{site_url}application#contact-sent" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-type="advanced">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="emailSent" id="emailSent">
                            <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />                               
                            <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value='<?php echo $merchantid; ?>' />                                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Your First Name *</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" required data-msg-required="Please enter your first name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Your Last Name *</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" required data-msg-required="Please enter your last name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Your Business Name *</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" required data-msg-required="Please enter your business name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="business_name" id="business_name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Your Phone Number *</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" required data-msg-required="Please enter your phone number." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone">
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Your email address *</label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" required data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Confirm Your email address *</label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" required data-msg-required="Emails must match." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control required email" equalTo='#email' name="emailConfirm" id="emailConfirm">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                  
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checked"> I agree to the <a href="{site_url}terms-and-conditions" target="_blank">terms & conditions</a>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Human Verification *</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="captcha form-control">
                                            <div class="captcha-image">
                                                <?php
                                                $_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha(array(
                                                    'min_length' => 6,
                                                    'max_length' => 6,
                                                    'min_font_size' => 22,
                                                    'max_font_size' => 22,
                                                    'angle_max' => 3
                                                ));

                                                $_SESSION['captchaCode'] = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];

                                                echo '<img src="' . "php/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php/" . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA code">';
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="6" data-msg-captcha="Wrong verification code." data-msg-required="Please enter the verification code." placeholder="Type the verification code." class="form-control" name="captcha" id="captcha">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" id="shortApplicationSubmit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" data-loading-text="Loading..." disabled="disabled">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();

include("php/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php");
include("php/php-mailer/class.phpmailer.php");


//  Step 1 - Enter your email address below.
$to = 'info@novawebdev.com';

$arrResult = array('response'=>'');

if(isset($_POST['emailSent'])) {

$subject = 'RTO Camera Application';

// Step 2 - If you don't want a "captcha" verification, remove that IF.
if (strtolower($_POST["captcha"]) == strtolower($_SESSION['captcha']['code'])) {

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $business_name = $_POST['business_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];
    // $emailConfirm = $_POST['emailConfirm'];

    // Step 3 - Configure the fields list that you want to receive on the email.
    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'First Name',
            'val' => $_POST['first_name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Last Name',
            'val' => $_POST['last_name']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Business Name',
            'val' => $_POST['business_name']
        ),
        3 => array(
            'text' => 'Phone Number',
            'val' => $_POST['phone']
        ),
        4 => array(
            'text' => 'Email',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        5 => array(
            'text' => 'Merchant ID',
            'val' => $_POST['merchantid']
        )
    );

    $message = "";

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();

    // Step 4 - If you don't receive the email, try to configure the parameters below:

    //$mail->Host = 'mail.yourserver.com';                // Specify main and backup server
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    //$mail->Username = 'username';                       // SMTP username
    //$mail->Password = 'secret';                         // SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['first_name'].' '.$_POST['last_name'];
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $first_name, $last_name);
    $mail->AddCC($email);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;  

    if($mail->Send()) {
       $arrResult['response'] = 'success';
    } else {
        $arrResult['response'] = 'error';
    }

} else {

    $arrResult['response'] = 'captchaError';

}
}
?>
```

I've been researching this for a few hours, and this is how far I've come.  I've never worked with PHP outside a basic copy paste for a contact form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. In your

```
<input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value='<?php echo $merchantid; ?>' />
```

make sure $merchantid is set with the get parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="<?php if ( isset( $_GET['merchantid'] ) ) echo $_GET['merchantid']; ?>" />
```

and then it'll be available as

```
$merchantid = $_POST['merchantid'];
```

in your processing function.

Comment: I pasted that same code, which I've had before, and it breaks my page.  Says: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: merchantid

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(688) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 153

line 153 is the line with the hidden php get

Comment: Does it also break if you load the page with that get parameter in the url? In any case, there should be an isset() check. See edited answer. To verify you're getting the variable into your form, view it in source.

Comment: I get an unexpected error "isset" and my page is completely broken.

Comment: sorry, this time forgot to add parenthesis around the if condition.

Comment: Ok, now says error on line 25, which is this: $merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];

Do I just need to put the $merchantid in the input?

Comment: Is that line in the PHP function? There you need to replace GET with POST, since you're posting your form data. `$merchantid = $_POST['merchantid'];`

Comment: I changed it to this: <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="<?php if ( isset( $_GET['merchantid'] ) ) echo $_POST['merchantid']; ?>" />

Still getting the blank field though.

Comment: in the form, inside the input tag, it needs to be GET. Inside the function in php, where you are sending your mail, it has to be POST.

Comment: This worked.  I was an idiot.  I was trying to add the query string on the actual page, so it wasn't able to "get" it.  I linked to the page with the query string and it worked to perfection.  Thanks